# Modifying file in vim and after restart the file is reset to unmodified

Tags: insert-mode

I have two monitors and the second one is detected as primary even tho I made the actual one primary in the settings. I found a hacky metod to make it primary and it involves changing the files. I used vim and saved the changes with ":qw" but after restart the file is reset to its original state and the monitors are still broken.

Comment: I'm not sure it is a vim  problem. Did you tried to modify the file with another editor?

Comment: Make sure you use `:wq`, not what you wrote. Also, you may not have the right to edit the file. In this case, use `sudo vi /path/to/file` to edit as root.

Comment: @Biggybi `sudo -e` or `sudoedit` is likely better :)

Comment: Good reminder, thanks. I use [eunuch](https://github.com/tpope/vim-eunuch)'s `:SudoEdit` when needed and completely forgot about the right ways.